# SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Помогите составить следующий запрос: Требуется вывести все сообщения определенного пользователя, НО так же требуется, конечно если это возможно, в одном запросе сразу же подсчитать количество сообщений определенного пользователя с определенной ячейкой, а именно с определенным значением у ячейки таблицы.

```
$userMessages = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `who`='$id_profile'");

$message = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($userMessages); $num_messages = mysqli_num_rows ($userMessages);
```

P.S. Думал использовать Join, хотя он тут и ни причем... 
P.S.S. Конечно, если это невозможно то как это сделать более логично ? я думаю под-запрос ещё один написать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать подзапрос:

```
SELECT *, (select count(*) FROM `messages` WHERE `who`='$id_profile') cnt
FROM `messages` WHERE `who`='$id_profile'
```

Comment: cnt что за оператор такой или что это такое вообще ?)

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, это не оператор, а псевдоним (alias)